# Counting Chains of Bounded Types

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, totient-function, stirling-numbers

You have pearl of 3 types.

Type 1 pearl can be of color from 1 to X.

Type 2 pearl can be of color from X+1 to X+Y

Type 3 pearl can be of color from X+Y+1 to X+Y+Z.

You have unlimited supply of pearls of each type and each color. You want to build some pearl chain. But you have 2 more additional constraints.

The total number of Type 1 and Type 3 pearls will be exactly A.

The total number of Type 2 and Type 3 pearls will be exactly B.

Given A, B, X, Y and Z (All <= N) calculate how many different pearl chains are possible. 2 chains are different if they have different length or there is a position in which they have different colored pearl.

The Answer should be closed form, or computable in O(Log(N)) time.

Solution Idea:

Sum t3 from 0 to min(A,B) of X^(A - t3) * Y^(B - t3) * Z^t3 * (A + B - t3)! / [ t3! (A - t3)! (B - t3)! ]

At which point we were stuck. What kind of combinatoric quantity is this? It's some type of Stirling or Euler numbers? Thanks!